# How to generate permutations while culling bad sequences?

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation

Problem Statement: I have 150 objects with weights and values attached to them.  The weights of the objects might change based on the order they are selected, typically about 70-80 items are selected.  I can only select up to a maximum weight, so all permutations that start with the same sequence need to be skipped once I've found a sub-solution with that sequence.  The goal is to maximize value.

I can trivially create all permutations with:

```
from itertools import permutations
for i in permutations(list(range(150))):
    # do something with i
```

However this will create many sequences that I don't need to check.  I can also restrict permutation length with r such that

```
from itertools import permutations
for i in permutations(list(range(150)), r=80):
    # do something with i
```

However for really bad sequences there will still be a lot of redundant checks.  Additionally this could stop before a 'best' solution.

I could do something like

```
from itertools import permutations
v = []
for i in permutations(list(range(150)), r=80):
    if v and v == i[:len(v)]:
        continue
    # do something with i
    v = i # would be some optimal subset of i
```

However this still takes a very long time to run as Python is still generating and checking the sequences.  Any thoughts on how I should approach this?  Ideally I would be able to run the checks in parallel.

More Background:  I am attempting to create optimized resource graphs for a game called Black Desert Online( graph example at somethinglovely.net/bdo/ ).  The graph has ~150 resource nodes that can each connect to a subset of 14 root nodes.  Intermediate nodes on the graph have weights associated with them.  Each city has a maximum amount of nodes it can be connected to and there is an additional weight cost for connecting a resource node to a city.  I was not having success with random graph generation coupled with a genetic algorithm for 'finding' an optimal solution.  Additionally just making greedy choices leads to a sub-optimal solution.  I am currently stumped on how to generate a brute force + comprehensive solution that will run in a reasonable period of time(reasonable being within a day on a reasonable desktop computer.

Comment: If you use the usual recursive algorithm, you can easily return from anywhere in the recursion to prune the whole sub-tree.

Comment: Was trying that before and ran into recursion depth errors.  But in over-engineering the problem I forgot about setrecursionlimit.  While I think this will still take longer to complete than I am willing to run the program, it does answer the question as I asked it.

Comment: If the weights of the objects changes based on the order they are selected, then that makes the problem much more difficult—because the weight of the same group of objects could be different depending on the order they were chosen. This seems like it implies you'd have to try all combinations of object in every permutation.

Comment: Can you describe in more detail how the problem works? More detailed answers may be possible with that

Comment: The problem was(is?):  Given a node weighted planar graph G=(V, E) with a set of roots R and a set of resources S(R and S are distinct from each other but both in G), select a set S' from S with maximum value that does not exceed a cost restriction.  Each node in S can only have 1 connection to a node in R counted.  Cost is the sum of node weights plus  a cost function on each node in R for the number of nodes in S connected to it(EG R1 increases cost by 0 for the first 4 connections from S, is 1 for 5, 2 for 6, 4 for 7, etc).

Comment: And each R node has a maximum number of connections it can support.  So there is some pathing in the original problem(There exist nodes that are in G that are not in R or S).  Which is why weights can change based on order.  As I was not having luck with other attempts I am trying to solve this with a brute-force/exhaustive solution.  However it is becoming apparent to me that I missed some obvious space/processing complexity issues.

Comment: Is the cost for an added connection just the sum of the weights of the extra edges plus the "connection penalty" (or however you call it, that cost that goes up for linking more nodes to a root)? Because then it seems like you don't have to focus on the order (just the binary fact whether an edge is in use, and separately the number of things connected to a root) and without optimizing the order as well you should have a much smaller problem. Maybe you can write it as a linear program too, to get a good pruning heurisitc.

Comment: Yes to your question and thank you for your help.  This gives me a much better area of possible solutions to explore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through the inventory list, one item at a time, and try packing both with and without that item (two recursions).  Report a solution when we reach one of two points:

1. No more items left to consider
2. The remaining list fits within our weight budget.

This takes care of the culling, by proactive construction.

Code:

```
items = [
    # Description, weight
    ("petrol", 10),
    ("clothes", 8),
    ("tents", 7),
    ("beer", 16),
    ("food", 20),
    ("teddy bear", 3),
    ("tank", 25),
    ("skin lotion", 2),
    ("library", 17),
    ("mortar", 9),
    ("cut lumber", 12),
    ("sports gear", 14),
]

limit = 20

def load(inventory, max_weight, current):

    still_okay = [item for item in inventory if item[1] <= max_weight]
    if len(still_okay) == 0:
        # Can't add any more; emit solution and back up
        print "RESULT", current
    else:
        # If the rest of the list fits in our weight budget,
        #   take everything.
        if sum([item[1] for item in still_okay]) <= max_weight:
            print "RESULT", current + still_okay
        else:
            item = still_okay.pop()
            # recur on two branches: one each with and without this item
            load(still_okay, max_weight - item[1], current + [item])
            load(still_okay, max_weight, current)

load(items, limit, [])
```

Output:

```
RESULT [('sports gear', 14), ('teddy bear', 3), ('skin lotion', 2)]
RESULT [('cut lumber', 12), ('skin lotion', 2), ('teddy bear', 3)]
RESULT [('cut lumber', 12), ('teddy bear', 3)]
RESULT [('cut lumber', 12), ('tents', 7)]
RESULT [('cut lumber', 12), ('clothes', 8)]
RESULT [('mortar', 9), ('skin lotion', 2), ('teddy bear', 3)]
RESULT [('mortar', 9), ('skin lotion', 2), ('tents', 7)]
RESULT [('mortar', 9), ('skin lotion', 2), ('clothes', 8)]
RESULT [('mortar', 9), ('teddy bear', 3), ('tents', 7)]
RESULT [('mortar', 9), ('teddy bear', 3), ('clothes', 8)]
RESULT [('mortar', 9), ('tents', 7)]
RESULT [('mortar', 9), ('clothes', 8)]
RESULT [('mortar', 9), ('petrol', 10)]
RESULT [('library', 17), ('skin lotion', 2)]
RESULT [('library', 17), ('teddy bear', 3)]
RESULT [('skin lotion', 2), ('teddy bear', 3), ('tents', 7), ('clothes', 8)]
RESULT [('skin lotion', 2), ('teddy bear', 3), ('clothes', 8)]
RESULT [('skin lotion', 2), ('teddy bear', 3), ('petrol', 10)]
RESULT [('skin lotion', 2), ('beer', 16)]
RESULT [('skin lotion', 2), ('tents', 7), ('clothes', 8)]
RESULT [('skin lotion', 2), ('tents', 7), ('petrol', 10)]
RESULT [('skin lotion', 2), ('petrol', 10), ('clothes', 8)]
RESULT [('teddy bear', 3), ('beer', 16)]
RESULT [('teddy bear', 3), ('tents', 7), ('clothes', 8)]
RESULT [('teddy bear', 3), ('tents', 7), ('petrol', 10)]
RESULT [('teddy bear', 3), ('clothes', 8)]
RESULT [('teddy bear', 3), ('petrol', 10)]
RESULT [('food', 20)]
RESULT [('beer', 16)]
RESULT [('tents', 7), ('clothes', 8)]
RESULT [('tents', 7), ('petrol', 10)]
RESULT [('petrol', 10), ('clothes', 8)]
```

Comment: This answers a simpler version of my problem.  Your solution assumes static weights while my version the order matters as it can change the weights.  However this should give me a much better approximation than my initial greedy algorithms.  I'll just need to figure out how to order the items a little before running to simulate realistic choice orders(and thus static weights).

Comment: Yes, I think this will work.  You'll need to insert weight updates at that first recursion step.  Perhaps reverse the order, so you do the "without" recursion, then alter weights, and finally make the "with" recursion call.